# how to move an object to form corner then stop?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

What this code should do is move an object to a chosen corner of the form, by clicking it, then it should stop when destination is reached, without using the (. location) property.

but in my code here, it keeps moving beyond the form border.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Timer1.Enabled = True
        End Sub


    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
           If Button1.Left = (Me.Width - Button1.Width) Then
             Timer1.Enabled = False
           Else
               Button1.Left += 10
               Button1.Top -= 10
           End If

        End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing by 10, not 1, so most likely you are **passing** the value `Me.Width - Button1.Width` without ever exactly equaling it.

Check to see if you're greater than your target, and use `Me.ClientRectangle.Width` instead of `Me.Width`:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim RightReached As Boolean = False
    If Button1.Left >= (Me.ClientRectangle.Width - Button1.Width) Then
        Button1.Left = Me.ClientRectangle.Width - Button1.Width
        RightReached = True
    Else
        Button1.Left += 10
    End If

    Dim TopReached As Boolean = False
    If Button1.Top <= 0 Then
        Button1.Top = 0
        TopReached = True
    Else
        Button1.Top -= 10
    End If

    If RightReached AndAlso TopReached Then
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i already tried incrementing by 1, and me.ClientRectangle.Width, still have the same issue.

Comment: Not sure where you're going wrong.  The above is tested code.  I've written it a little more verbosely to hopefully help you see what needs to be done.

Comment: It should be `If Button1.Left + 10 >= (Me.ClientRectangle.Width - Button1.Width) Then...`

Comment: thank you guyz VERY much, it works perfectly, and i understand more about the performance of the operation now.